# Problem using Eigen math library with opengl

Tags: opengl, vbo, eigen

I'm currently trying to use Eigen math library with Opengl. I've some typedefs for Vector3f from Eigen, say Vec3, so that I can use it as a coord for my vertices. I also have a structure for a vertex with coord (vec3), normal (vec3) and color(vec4). When I try to use vertex arrays (I'll use VBOs once I make vertex arrays work properly) it seems there is a problem with OpenGL processing Eigen's Vector3f as coords... Has any of you dealed with these issues??

Comment: isn't using Eigen kind of overkill? I've written my own classes for vec4/mat4 to ensure compatibility with OpenGL. The most complex thing you'll likely do is invertinng a matrix and this is still trivial for a 4x4 matrix. I guess even QR decomposition aint that hard to do yourself for a 4x4 matrix, so why Eigen?

Comment: in case you reconsider this, you can use my classes if you like (i wont claim they were the best or in anyway complete, but they've served me well for long). here they are: http://ioctl.eu/browser/opengl/base/src/mat4.h and http://ioctl.eu/browser/opengl/base/src/vec4.h

Comment: "problem": Doesn't display, displays wrong, crashes, what?

Answer (score 2):

In Eigen, Vectors are Matrices (cf http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/e17630a40408/doc/AsciiQuickReference.txt line 12)

I suspect Matrices to own not only the data, but only additional information, like its size. What's more, it packing may be weird.

So, what does sizeof(Eigen::Vector3f) returns ? If it's 3xsizeof(float) = 12, the problem is elsewhere.

How do you setup and draw your array, by the way ?

Answer (score 2):

Eigen3 actually has [wrappers](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__OpenGLSUpport__Module.html) for OpenGL now. This seems to be the cleanest way getting what you want.